# Developing a strategy to win a game of picking elements from $S_n$

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-game-theory

> Given a integer $n>1$, Let $S_n$ be the group of permutations of the numbers $1,2,\dots n$. Two players, $A$ and $B$, play the following game. Taking turns, they select elements(one element at a time) from the group $S_n$. It is  forbidden to select an element that had been already selected. The game ends when the selected elements generate the whole group $S_n$. The player who made the last move loses. The first move is made by $A$. Which player has a winning strategy?

My attempt involves finding

> What elements of $S_n$ can generate $S_n$?

I know that $(123 \dots n)$ and $(12)$ can generate $S_n$.

But we are supposed to look for all other such set of elements which can generate $S_n$.

How do I solve this?

Comment: "all other" sets might be a bit ambitious.

Comment: The probability that two random elements of $S_n$ generate $S_n$ approaches $1$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: @shaun The actual question is "Second Question". I thought that the first question is necessary to solve  the actual question. My attempt involves solving first question to solve second question

Comment: Okay. I suggest that you [edit] the question, then, to make that clear. It might be closed as too broad otherwise, since it's easy to overlook such detail.

Answer (score 1):

I guess for $n=1$, A must choose the identity, which generates $S_n$, so B wins.

For $n=2$ A wins by choosing the identity, and for $n=3$ A wins by choosing a $3$-cycle, such as $(1,2,3)$.

For $n \ge 4$, all maximal subgroups of $S_n$ have even order, and the subgroup generated by the elements chosen so far will eventually be maximal, so B wins.